# Find tree diameter or center

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I want to find center in a graph that doesn't have cycles. I heard, that this is how I find a diameter:

1. Take random vertex A
2. Find such vertex B, that distance to it is maximal
3. Find such vertex C, that distance from B to C is maximal
4. BC is diameter

And then I just divide it equally.

But how to prove this diameter finding algorithm? Why is it valid?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for problem 4 in [HW3_Solution.pdf](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/373/hw/keys/HW3_Solution.pdf) gives a detailed proof.
There is also the same question [Prove traversing a k-ary tree twice yields the diameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989578/prove-traversing-a-k-ary-tree-twice-yields-the-diameter) asked on Stack Overflow.